# Возврат значения из WebView (Kotlin)

Tags: android, kotlin, webview

Всех приветствую. Подскажите, пожалуйста, как мне вернуть значение из объекта **WebViewClient** в класс главной активности (вытащить)? Значение генерируется в методе **onPageFinished**. Объект класса **WebViewClient** создан и используется в классе главной активности.